# JavaScript sum all of the values in each object in an array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with 2 objects.

`var sum = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4},{a:2, b:3, c:4, d:5}];`

How can I sum the value in each object using just reduce/map/filter/forEach function?

The output should be `[10, 14]`

Answer (score 6):

You could map the objects and the values by iterating the keys of ths object and add the value of all properties.

Methods used:

- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for returning a result for every item
- [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for getting all own properties of an object
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for summing up the values

```js
var data = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, d: 5 }],
    sum = data.map(function (object) {
        return Object.keys(object).reduce(function (sum, key) {
            return sum + object[key];
        }, 0);
    });

console.log(sum);
```

Sum without key `'a'`

```js
var data = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }, { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4, d: 5 }],
    sum = data.map(function (object) {
        return Object.keys(object).reduce(function (sum, key) {
            return sum + (key !== 'a' && object[key]);
        }, 0);
    });

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Or, equivalently, using shorthand: `sum = data.map(o => Object.keys(o).reduce((s,k) => s + o[k], 0));`

Comment: Thanks, how about if I want to sum (b c d) only, except the (a). The output will be [9, 12].

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using [*Array.prototype.reduce()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

```js
var sum = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4},{a:2, b:3, c:4, d:5}],
    result = sum.reduce(function (r, o) {
        r.push(Object.keys(o).reduce(function(r, b){ return r + o[b]; }, 0));
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what if you have object like this  **category:{'1':200,'2':300}**

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, `o` is each object in the array, `t` is the accumulating total sum, `p` is the property of the object being added.

```js
const sum = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4},{a:2, b:3, c:4, d:5}];

const result = sum.map(o => Object.keys(o).reduce((t, p) => t + o[p], 0));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

es6 for of version:

```
let sum = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4},{a:2, b:3, c:4, d:5}];

let result = [], objSum;
for (let item of sum) {
    objSum = 0;
    for (let property in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            objSum += item[property];
        }
    }

    result.push(objSum);
}
console.log(result);//[10, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows in pure JS in 2017.

```js
var sum = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4},{a:2, b:3, c:4, d:5}],
   sums = sum.map(a => Object.values(a).reduce((p,c) => p+c));
console.log(sums);
```

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use a utility library like Lodash.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var sum = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4},{a:2, b:3, c:4, d:5}];
var result = _.map(sum, function(obj) {
      return _.reduce(_.values(obj), function(sum, n) {
          return sum + n;
      }, 0);
});
console.log(result);
```